# Find and remove specified HTML tags using Html Agility Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get Html Agility Pack to work in my case. I need to detect all script elements in an existing HTML page and remove them, saving the changes to another file. Here, bodyNode returns the correct number of script tags, but I can't remove them. The new file still has those tags.

```
if (doc.DocumentNode != null)         
{
     var bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script");          
     if (bodyNode != null)             
     {
          bodyNode.Clear(); // clears the collection only                    
     } 

     doc.Save("some file");        
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
foreach(HtmlNode node in bodyNode)
{
   node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}
```