# c# Regex Remove all <img/> tags from string

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm having a htmlString witch has a lot of markup in it. I want to leave all the markup as it is except from the `<img/>` - tags. All these I want to remove. How can I do that?

I know I can do somthing like this to take just the img tag into a new string.

```
string imgUrl = Regex.Match(myHtmlMarkupDiv, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value
```

Is there a imilar way of doing it with Regex?

Comment: I would use HtmlAgilityPack instead of regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333363/find-and-remove-specified-html-tags-using-html-agility-pack or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787449/html-agility-pack-removing-unwanted-tags-without-removing-content

Comment: Several posts already exist : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729531/regex-to-trap-img-tag-both-versions
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: And the most infamous one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1336590